# UICollectionView manage elements scroll speed by time

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a UICollectionView with paging enabled and a one cell on the screen. 
I scroll elements programatically. 
How can I manage the scroll speed?

For example:
I want to scroll the current cell out of the screen for 500ms, and then wait at the next cell for 200ms and then scroll to screen for 300ms.
Is it possible to implement?